# USB to rs232 adapter

Tags: usb, rs-232

I have 6 Prolific rs232-USB adapters that are connected to a windows 10 box. I can retrieve information about each of them with Python. However, they look identical except 'LOCATION'. There is a field with a serial number but it is identical for all of them.

I know that some devices have FTDI or Prolific chips inside that make them look like USB device but everything is done in as serial later on. Those devices have serial number field changed to something more meaningful. I also read that more expensive rs232-usb adapters have unique serial numbers. Do you know of any rs232 to usb adapters with unique serial numbers?

I have found [documentation](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_124_User_Guide_For_FT_PROG.pdf) on how EEPROM can be rewritten on FTDI chips. It seems to me that FTDI chips can be reprogrammed to include a meaningful serial number. This would be a useful feature to have too.

I have checked if I have a genuine Prolific chip and I do.
[image]

Prolific also provides a tool to [reprogram EEPROM](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?pcid=41&showlevel=0017-0037-0041). Though, the tools say it requires 6.5V to do that. The schematics of 5V->6.5V USB adapter can be requested from Prolific themself.

"
When writing data into the internal OTPROM (One-Time Programming ROM) of PL2303HXD/EA, it is
required to supply 6.5V to the device while executing the program. Prolific provides the schematic
diagram for the USB 5V-to-6.5V port converter upon request so customers can produce the converters
themselves. Contact Prolific for more information.
"

Comment: Sounds like the manufacturer of the RS232 to USB adapters you bought used fake prolific chips, a pretty common issue it seems - There is a tool to check to see if you have fakes - https://www.trishtech.com/2018/02/how-to-check-if-prolific-usb-to-uart-adapter-is-fake/

Comment: @Lawrence I do have a genuine chip.